# Almacenar palabras de manera "global"

Tags: array, c, string

me encuentro leyendo un archivo de entrada. Con el siguiente estructura de código:

```
char *terminalesSalida[200];
int cantTerminales = 0;
char *terminales[] = {"el","perro","gato"};
FILE * entrada = fopen(argv[1], "r");                   
    if(entrada == NULL){                                                
        printf("Error: El archivo de entrada no existe.");      
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        ...    //trozo de codigo
               terminalesSalida[cantTerminales] = terminales[i];
               cantTerminales = cantTerminales + 1;
        ...    //trozo de codigo
    }
    fclose(entrada);
```

Las palabras se guardan correctamente en terminalesSalida. El problema es que al cerrar el archivo de entrada, las palabras almacenadas en terminalesSalida al parecer pierden su valor (talvez esto ocurra antes del fclose(entrada)). Busco una manera de almacenar cada palabra de terminales[i], de manera "global", porque después necesito trabajar con esas palabras.

Comment: Hace mucho que no uso C, pero me parece que te falta asignar memoria. Siempre que creas un puntero tienes que tener presente qué región de memoria será. `terminalesSalida` es un puntero a un array de 200 chars. Te serviría lo mismo hacer directamente `char terminalesSalida[200]`. Pero sospecho que quieres almacenar muchas palabras, por lo que debería ser un array bidimensional, o puntero a puntero y hacer todos los `malloc` necesarios. No es que por ser puntero mágicamente puedes almacenar cualquier cantidad de elementos. Por ejemplo, `int *valor` es puntero a UN int, no es un array.

Comment: Y unos detalles finales: si usas `return`, no es necesario el `else`. Menor anidación es código más fácil de entender. Y al final puedes hacer directamente `cantTerminales++`.

Comment: Perdón, aunque `[]` tiene precedencia sobre `*`, `terminalesSalida` es un array de 200 punteros a chars. Mientras a cada puntero le asignes una dirección ya asignada, va a funcionar, mientras eso apuntado siga existiendo todo el tiempo que lo necesites. [Link útil](https://overiq.com/c-programming-101/array-of-pointers-to-strings-in-c/). `cantTerminales` hasta cuánto crece? Cuánto vale `i` y hasta cuánto crece?

Comment: El valor de i inicialmente es cero. Se pretende que llegue a un valor de 31 (tamaño constante de terminales[]), mediante ciclo iterativo.

Comment: Cabe destacar que no se almacenan las palabras en las 31 iteraciones, si no se guardan como 5-10 palabras aproximadamente

Comment: ¿`terminales` tiene 32 elementos? Creo que tendrías que incluir más código. ¿Por qué no haces un `printf` de los valores en varios puntos del programa para ver cuándo se pierden?

Comment: ¿Pudiste resolverlo?